# interrogative and affirmative sentence constructions

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

Say we have the following sentence :

> The further information I need is to know in which building is the
>   class held.

Is it grammatically correct to place "is" where it's placed in the sentence, or should it be moved after the word "class", like this:

> ...in which building the class is held.

The sentence isn't interrogative, so my guess is the second variant is fine, but sometimes I become quite dubious(this time, for example).

Comment: *need to know* is a common usage so I wouldn't break it up. So "The further information I *need to know* is in which building is the class held.

Comment: I don't think the word-order you suggested is correct(that's the sheer point of my question). The last part of the sentence is interrogative, while the whole sentence was meant to be affirmative.

Comment: If you don't want it to be interrogative, how about "The further information I need to know is in which building the class *is* held."

Answer (score 0):

You do need an "is" in your sentence.

> The information I need to know in which building is the class held.

Is definitely incomplete.  The "is" is part of the direct object - there's no main verb.

SUBJECT:  The information that I need to know

PREDICATE VERB: _________(is)_______________

PREDICATE NOUN: (the question itself:  "In which building is the class held")

Therefore,

> The information I need to know is in which building is the class held.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "The information I need to know is in which building the class is held."